# Orthogonal complement of a subspace in $l^2$

Tags: hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Consider $l^2$ as a Hilbert space with the usual inner product. It's quite easy to see that the subspace $X$ consisting of the sequences $(x_n)_{n\ge1}$ such that $x_{2n} = nx_{2n-1}$ for all $n\ge1$ is closed in $l^2$, so we know $l^2 = X + X^\perp$. I've been trying to figure out what $X^\perp$ is explicitly, but I can't seem to get anywhere. The obvious choice to me was the subspace $Y$ of those sequences such that $x_{2n} = -nx_{2n-1}$ for all $n\ge1$, but I think $X+Y \ne l^2$.

Comment: I'd rather try $y_{2n}=-\dfrac1ny_{2n-1}$, I think. Your $Y$ does not seem orthogonal to $X$.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I didn't see that! I'd try if your choice of $Y$ works - it seems like it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer. $X^\perp=Y=\big\{\{x_n\}\in\ell^2\,\,\,\text{where}\,\,\, x_{2n}=-x_{2n-1}/n\big\}$.

a. Show that, if $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, then $(x,y)=0$.

b. Write any element of $\ell^2$ as a sum of elements of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Yup, I've got it. Thanks.